# Eliminating the characters that are not a date in R

Tags: regex, r

I have some data frame, df with a column with dates that are in the following format:

```
    pv$day
    01/01/13 00:00:00
    03/01/13 00:02:03
    04/03/13 00:10:15

....
```

I would like to eliminate the timestamp, just leaving the date (e.g. `01/01/13` for the first row). I have tried both using `sapply()` to apply the `strsplit()` function, and tried to filter the content using a regex, but don't seem to have quite gotten it right in either case. This:

```
 sapply(pv$day, function(x) strsplit(toString(x), ' '))
```

gives me the column with the correct split, but indexing with either `[1]` or `[[1]]` does not return the first element of the split.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub`:

```
vec <- c("01/01/13 00:00:00", "03/01/13 00:02:03", "04/03/13 00:10:15")

sub(" .+", "", vec)
# [1] "01/01/13" "03/01/13" "04/03/13"
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple, flexible solution is to use strptime and strftime.  Here is an example that uses your dates from the example above:

```
# Your dates
t <- c("01/01/13 00:00:00","03/01/13 00:02:03", "04/03/13 00:10:15")

# Convert character strings to dates
z <- strptime(t, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS")

# Convert dates to string, omitting the time
z.date <- strftime(z,"%d/%m/%y")

# Print the first date
z.date[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice way to use `sapply`, it uses `strsplit` to split at the space

```
> d <- c("01/01/13 00:00:00", "03/01/13 00:02:03", "04/03/13 00:10:15")
> sapply(strsplit(d, " "), `[`, 1)
# [1] "01/01/13" "03/01/13" "04/03/13"
```

And also, you could use `stringr::word` if you just want a character vector.

```
> library(stringr)
> word(d)
# [1] "01/01/13" "03/01/13" "04/03/13"
```

Comment: This seems to get the expected format `format(as.Date(d, format="%d/%m/%y"), "%d/%m/%y")#[1] "01/01/13" "03/01/13" "04/03/13"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a look around assertion:

```
vec <- c("01/01/13 00:00:00", "03/01/13 00:02:03", "04/03/13 00:10:15")
gsub(pattern = "(?=00).*$", replacement =  "", vec, perl = TRUE)
[1] "01/01/13 " "03/01/13 " "04/03/13 "
```

The pattern looks for anything at the end of a string that begins with double 00, and removes it.